# Upgrade Magento from 2.2.6 to 2.3

Tags: composer, magento2.3

I am trying to update Magento from version 2.2.6 to 2.3, but i get this errors:

sh-4.2# composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 --no-update
./composer.json has been updated

sh-4.2# composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - The requested package magento/magento-cloud-metapackage could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more details.
 - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

Read https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for further common problems.

This is the composer version:

sh-4.2# composer --version
Composer version 1.7.3 2018-11-01 10:05:06

And this is the composer file.

sh-4.2# more composer.json

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "version": "2.1.7",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.3.0",
        "composer/composer": "@alpha",
        "codeko/redsys": "3.0.6",
        "eusonlito/magento2-language-es_es": "^0.0.8",
        "mageplaza/magento-2-spanish-language-pack": "dev-master",
        "lcbrq/magento2-dateformatpatch": "^1.0",
        "magento/magento-cloud-metapackage": "2.3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.2.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.2.2",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.5.2",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "~3.0.0",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.10.1"
    },
    "config": {
        "use-include-path": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
            "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": "app/code/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "alpha",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "repositories": {
        "0": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        },
        "magento": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/packages.json"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Regards,
JOINSO

Comment: Congrats on finding a solution to your problem! Please mark your question as answered!

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I add an answer, that is better than put it inside the question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved using following steps:

Come back to the previous version of composer.json
Following instruction from How to Upgrade magento version from 2.2.X to 2.3.0?

In the last step, it says: `sjparkinson/static-review` is not required in your `composer.json` and has not been removed `fabpot/php-cs-fixer` is not required in your `composer.json` and has not been removed

Run: # composer upgrade

Then you can get errors like this when you try to do:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade ... Class 'Zend\Mvc\Controller\LazyControllerAbstractFactory' not found ...
```

So you must to edit the `composer.json` file and modify the autoload section:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
        "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
        "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
        "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
    },
},
```

Then run: `> composer dumpautoload`

And rerun: `> php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

And it works!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error while upgrading from Magento 2.2.6 Enterprise to Magento 2.3.2 Enterprise. This error occurs most probably due to composer issue. I reinstalled the composer then I executed the below commands and it upgraded my Magento version without any error.

composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.3.2 --no-update

then

composer update